# WFS with CQL_FILTER=BBOX return empty layer

Tags: qgis, wfs, extents, filter, cql

This is the first time I using WFS. I'm trying to get features with this WFS request inside a BBOX:

```
uri=https://wxs.ign.fr/choisirgeoportail/geoportail/wfs?service=WFS&srsName=EPSG:4326&version=auto&request=GetFeature&typename=CADASTRALPARCELS.PARCELLAIRE_EXPRESS:parcelle&CQL_FILTER=BBOX(the_geom,4.798409351,45.714813854,4.864118669,45.760824683)

parcelle_layer = QgsVectorLayer( uri, "parcelle", "WFS" )
```

This request returns an empty layer.

The request works when the `CQL_FILTER` is not a `BBOX` (ex: `CQL_FILTER=code_insee=69123`)  It does not work when I add the optional CRS inside the `BBOX` like this:

`BBOX(the_geom,4.798409351,45.714813854,4.864118669,45.760824683,EPSG:4326)`

I checked the `GetCapabilities` and `DescribeFeatureType` of the source. By default, the CRS of the source is EPSG:4326.

Is there a mistake in my request? Or is there another way to get features inside the BBOX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the `BBOX` directly rather than as a CQL filter (see https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html).

I find that

```
https://wxs.ign.fr/choisirgeoportail/geoportail/wfs?service=wfs&srsName=EPSG:4326&request=getfeature&typename=CADASTRALPARCELS.PARCELLAIRE_EXPRESS:parcelle&BBOX=45.714813854,4.798409351,45.760824683,4.864118669
```

works fine. Note I removed your `version=auto` (this is invalid, though QGis might fix it for you) and flipped your axis order to be latitude, longitude (assuming this is France) and your CQL filter might well work if you do that too.

Comment: Thanks Ian for your help!